# angular data-table filter on inputs in td

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I'm using this library https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

I'm placing input fields inside of the table data like so:

```
  <td> <input type="text" ng-model="item.tiersk" /> </td>
```

However, when I do this I am no longer able to filter by order using the built in table head filter feature.  I have other table data in other columns that work like so:

```
                    <td> {{item.expensetype.expensename}}</td>
```

Is there away to add a value to the td element to sort on? Maybe something like this:

```
<td value="{{item.tiersk}}"> <input type="text" ng-model="item.tiersk" /> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular just reflects the array of data that's there.
The best way to sort based on an input is to use a setter

```
i.e.
set myfield(s: string){
this.myarray[x].myfield = s;
this.sort(myarray)
}
```

Where x can be set by picking the row on the UI. `(click)=pickRow()` function.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there away to add a value to the td element to sort on?

Yes, see [HTML5 data-* attributes - cell data](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html). Add a `data-sort` attribute to your `<td>`'s :

```
<td data-sort="{{item.tiersk}}"> <input type="text" ng-model="item.tiersk" /> </td>
```

Use `data-sort` for special values when the tables is sorted, i.e user clicking on column headers; `data-filter` for the search box.